# Why doesn't inotify update?

Tags: c, filesystems, minecraft, inotify

I'm writing an inotify watcher in C for a Minecraft server. Basically, it watches server.log, gets the latest line, parses it, and if it matches a regex; performs some actions.

The program works fine normally through "echo string matching the regex >> server.log", it parses and does what it should. However, when the string is written to the file automatically via Minecraft server, it doesn't work until I shut down the server or (sometimes) log out.

I would post code, but I'm wondering if it doesn't have something to do with ext4 flushing data to disk or something along those lines; a filesystem problem. It would be odd if that were the case though, because "tail -f server.log" updates whenever the file does.

Comment: Does the server actually flush the contents to disk on every write?  Is there something you could do to force it to do so?

Comment: I certainly hope it does. If nobody knows the problem off hand, I'll definitely look through the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved my own problem. It turned out the server was writing to the log file faster than the watcher could read from it; so the watcher was getting out of sync.

I fixed it by adding a check after it processes the event saying "if the number of lines currently in the log file is more than the recorded length of the log, reprocess the file until the two are equal."

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Presumably that is because you are watching for `IN_CLOSE` events, which may not occur until the server shuts down (and closes the log file handle). See [man inotify(7)](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) for valid mask parameters for the `inotify_add_watch()` call. I expect you'll want to use `IN_WRITE`.

Comment: Actually, I was using `IN_MODIFY`. I will check out `IN_WRITE` in a bit. Thanks!

Comment: There isn't a mask called `IN_WRITE`. `IN_MODIFY` seems to be the closest thing to what you're describing, which loops back to my original problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your theory is more than likely correct, the log file is being buffered by the OS, and the log writer has no flushing of that buffer, so everything will remain in the buffer till the file is closed or the buffer is full. A fast way to test is to start up the log to the point where you know it would have written events to the log, then forcibly close it so it cannot close the handle, if the log is empty is definitly the buffer. If you can get hold of the file handle/descriptor, you can use `setbuf` to remove buffering, at the cost of performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will definitely try this later today! When you say to use `setbuf`, are you saying to attempt to transfer the file descriptor from the running Java process (possibly by writing it to a file on startup,) to the C watcher, then using `setbuf` from it? Are the two different languages compatible in that aspect?

Comment: @screennameless: the underlying OS file descriptors are the same, so if you can get the already open handle you can then remove buffering, I'm not too sure how to do that under linux though :|

Comment: Thanks, ill definitely try this!  The simplest way I can think to pass the descriptor is by writing it to a file whenever its opened. I will try implementing this later.